# Bottom Sheet NPE при закрытии

Tags: java, android, material-design, sdk, android-appcompat

Проблема состоит в том, что в версиях ниже 5.0 при закрытии bottom sheet вылетает нпе, в версии 5.0 и выше - все нормально.

```
05-09 22:06:40.385 15759-15759/com.asgard.power E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderBehavior.onInterceptTouchEvent(HeaderBehavior.java:60)
                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.performIntercept(CoordinatorLayout.java:420)
                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout.java:472)
```

Так же, если нажать на любое место в табах, и свайпнуть в любую из сторон - так же вылетает нпе(не знаю, пригодится ли эта информация).

Насчет примера кода-это самый обычный bottom sheet из линеар лаяутов и текствьюшек. Описан в главном хмл(не в фрагменте), но имеет непосредственное отношение к recycleView находящемуся в фрагменте.

p.s Падает приложение именно по закрытию, при открытии все работает как нужно.
На версиях 5.0 и выше все вообще работает в целом, как нужно.

```
public class BehaviorController extends BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback {

private static BottomSheetBehavior behavior;

public BehaviorController(BottomSheetBehavior behavior) {
    BehaviorController.behavior = behavior;

}

public static BottomSheetBehavior getBehavior(){
    return behavior;
}

@Override
public void onStateChanged(@NonNull final View bottomSheet, int newState) {


    switch (newState) {
        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
            bottomSheet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;
        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:

        /*    bottomSheet.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {*/
                    behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                    behavior.setPeekHeight(0);
          /*      }
            });*/

            break;
        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
           // bottomSheet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            behavior.setPeekHeight(400);

            break;

    }
}


@Override
public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {


//    behavior.setState(slideOffset > 0 ? behavior.STATE_EXPANDED : behavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
    bottomSheet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Log.d("Shit", "Slide" + behavior.getState());

}
```

}

Код в активити:

```
  private static void hideSheet(View bottomSheet, final BottomSheetBehavior behavior){
    bottomSheet.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
        }
    });
}

private void initBottomSheetBehavior() {
  //  RecycleFragment frag = (RecycleFragment )getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.recyclefragment123456);


    frameSheet = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framesheet);

    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator);

    bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.framesheet);
    behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    Log.d("Sheet", "behavior " + behavior);
    hideSheet(bottomSheet,behavior);
    RecycleFragment.getInstance().setContext(this);
    RecycleFragment.getInstance().setBehaviorSheet(behavior, frameSheet);

    behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BehaviorController(behavior));


}
```

Comment: привести код сможете? или как закрываете?

Comment: Какая версия библиотеки совместимости у Вас?

Comment: @VAndrJ
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'

Comment: Возможно вернулась проблема, описанная https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183166 Попробуйте решения из 2, 3 и 40 ответов.

Comment: @VAndrJ не помог ни один из ответов, во время переопределения, разве что dispatchTouchEvent вместо полного краша приложения - оно замерзло в одном состоянии, не реагируя ни на что.